# On smaller resolution screens my website despite fitting always has a useless horizontal scroll bar

Tags: html, css, layout

On smaller resolution screens my website despite fitting always has a useless horizontal scroll bar. 
I'm wondering if anyone can give me any tips to make my website fit the screen better?

If you are using a laptop it will be easy to notice that the horizontal scroll bar moves too far right to only blank grey. My content is correctly centered but the background length is too long.

Here is my CSS for the background and the container holding my content.

```
body {
width: auto;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
text-align:center;
background: #E8E8E8;
}

.page {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
width: 1100px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: quick tip: you can update the margin style in the body selector to margin:0;

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the container size.

1100 pixels is a little bit too much for most small displays. Even a screen with a resolution of 1080 x 720 would have to use a scroll bar to display the remaining 20 pixels.

Comment: I think his problem is with scrollbar appearing even when container is totally fit within browser viewport

Comment: Still, with a fixed with of any number of pixels any screen with a lower resolution x-dimension has to add a horizontal scrollbar. I admit, I have not checked the site's complete code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Why are you loading tons of css/js in your body ?!

Second: Your container div has a 1100 pixels width, causing a scrollbar for any resolution lower than that.

Comment: Can you explain more about about the "css/js in your body?"

Comment: On your website you load alot of javascript/css after the `<body>` tag instead of loading it in the `<head>..</head>`. You should load css/javascript in the `<head>..</head>` of your page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your #topnav navigation panel is too wide and it also has left offset of 320 px. Try to make its width equal to 780px

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practise to use `%` instead of `px` while developing for responsive design.Since you have hardcoded the width you will always get a scrollbar in screen size less than 1100px.
I suggest you use 
`#container {
    width: 99%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ffffff;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set the overflow of your body or container to hidden. This will remove the scrollbar for you.

in your css try adding:

```
body{overflow-x:hidden;}
```

An alternative approach is to use media queries to resize your container depending on the native screen size. For example if displaying the page on a mobile device with a maximum screen width of say 300px, you could add the following to your css

```
@media screen and (max-width:300px){
    #container{width:300px;}
}
```

You might like to read this article on responsive design also: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

hope this helps